# Using "Mongojs.ObjectID" in Server linked to Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm using the MEAN stack to build a web app. I am trying to filter data coming from the server by ObjectId based on params in my controller. My params work for key-values, such as filtering by name, but filtering by ObjectID does not work. I am using MongoJS with Mongojs.ObjectID.

Controller.js:

```
var refresh = function() {
    $http.get('/collection', {params:{"_id":"111100000111"}}).success(function(response) {
        console.log("Success");
        $scope.collection = response;
    });
};

refresh();
```

Server.js:

```js
app.get('/collection', function(req,res){
  if(req.query.id){
    db.users.find({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.query.id)},function (err, docs) { console.log(docs); res.json(docs); }); 
  }
  else{
    db.users.find(function (err, docs) { console.log(docs); res.json(docs); });
  }
});
```

Because the server side function runs as an if-else, the "if" fails in this case, and it goes to the "else", which brings back all documents. I've tried almost every combination of adding a "_" before "id" and adding/removing quotes from "id" or "_id". Different combinations have brought back "null", an empty array, or have gone to the "else" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `_id` as a query parameter.

So this is what your GET request looks like:
/collection?_id=111100000111

However you're looking at `id` instead of `_id` in your `if` statement and inside the `find` function.

So it should look like this:

```
app.get('/collection', function(req,res) {
    var _id = req.query._id;
    if(_id) {
        db.users.find({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(_id)},function (err, docs) { console.log(docs); res.json(docs); }); 
    }
    else {
        db.users.find(function (err, docs) { console.log(docs); res.json(docs); });
    }
});
```